# Extraction of specific data column in .txt file

Tags: c++

I have a text file (data.txt) with 4 columns of data (1st column is time and 2nd, 3rd and 4th are specific data) and I want to write a program that extract one of the channel that it contains, calling it by its name so it creates a new file with only 2 columns (1st the time, 2nd the channel extracted).
The command line should be `extract data.txt channel_2.txt`.

I am a very new beginner in C++, I know the reading/writing thing (ofstream/ifstream/stream) but I am not sure I can create a new .txt file (with a different name of the original) with these classes.

I started to write some code, it is very basic and incomplete but as I say I have no experience in C++ (so please be comprehensive :) )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{   
    int index
    cout << "enter the index of the column to keep :  " << endl;
    cin >> index;
    
    ???
    
    
    // open file for writing  
    string filename("data.txt");
    ofstream file(filename._str());
    if(file)
    {
        file << data << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else
    { 
        cerr << "impossible to open file" << endl;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the data.txt file looks like :

```
%MC_DataTool ASCII conversion
%
%t              El 12           El 45           El 86
%[ms]           [microV]        [microV]        [microV]
0.000           0.83            -4.58           3.75
0.100           -8.33           -2.08           2.50
0.200           -10.00          -0.42           0.83
0.300           -9.58           -3.75           -8.75
0.400           -2.50           -2.50           -5.00
0.500           -5.42           -2.92           -9.58
...
59999.800       -3.33           2.50            -2.50
59999.900       1.67            -1.25           -2.08
60000.000       -2.92           -0.42           -0.42
```

And ideally the output should be as I explained, like that :

```
%time channel_2 
0.000000 -4.580000 
0.100000 -2.080000 
0.200000 -0.420000 
0.300000 -3.750000
...
```

Any help, comments or advices are more than welcome !
Thank you all.

Comment: I highly recommend searching the internet or minimally StackOverflow for "c++ read extract column".  This question has been answered too many times already.

Comment: Also, there are too many doubts you mention before having tried. Don't ask for solutions to tasks unless you can describe what your problem is. For example: "I am not sure I can create a new .txt file [...] with these classes" -- why don't you simply try? As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have search in stackoverflow, cplusplus, codeguru and others but I do not find the questions to all my answers, that's why I ask here, for some specific advices

Comment: In the C++ textbook, or class, where this assignment is given: the relevant chapter or class notes must present all necessary material that's needed to implement this task. Is there something in the explanation of the relevant parts of C++ which is unclear to you?

Comment: @гиви `struct record { double columns[4]; };` `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, record& r) { return is >> r.column[0] >> r.column[1] >> r.column[2] >> r.column[3]; }` could be a start. Extracting from streams is a common topic here. See if you can't find something about "_overloading `operator>>`_"  or similar.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik indeed it is an assignment. What it is not clear for this task is how to refer to an index of a column, I saw that C++ read line by line and can not do it by column

Comment: @гиви You can read line by line, discard lines that start with `%` then put the line in an `std::istringstream` and extract the 4 columns using what I showed above. You'll then be able to access the columns 0 to 3 in each `record`

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you I will have a look to what you said.

Comment: If you have a question about your assignment, your instructor will be the best resource to get any help. They are paid to teach you, this is their job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> database;
typedef std::vector<double> DB_Row;
//...
double column1, column2, column3, column4;
while (file >> column1 >> column2 >> column3 >> column4)
{
    DB_Row row;
    row.push_back(column1);
    row.push_back(column2);
    row.push_back(column3);
    row.push_back(column4);
    database.push_back(row);
}
```

The above code reads in your data as a *matrix* or 2D array.
To access the 2nd column of row 4:

```
double value = database[3][1]; // Remember, 0 based indexing
```

**Edit 1:  access column 2 for all rows**
Reminder, column 2 is represented by index value of 1 (0 is the index for column 1).

```
const unsigned int index_column_2 = 1;
const unsigned int ROW_COUNT = database.size();
for (unsigned int row = 0u; row < ROW_COUNT; ++row)
{
    std::cout << "value at row: " << row
              << ", column 2: " << database[row][index_column_2]
              << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to access the 2nd column of every rows ?

Comment: See my Edit 1.  You should read up on loops, nested loops, `vector` and nested `vector`.